# List not animating when updating it using 'react-transition-group'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css, react-transition-group

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

```
const CardsContainer = (props: CardsContainerProps) => {

    const { cards } = props
  
    let inactiveCards: Array<{ 
      card: Card
      active: boolean
    }>
  
    inactiveCards = cards.map((card) => {
      return { card: card, active: false }
    })
  
    const [updatedCards, updateCards] = useState(inactiveCards)
  
    const updateCardsById = (personId: string | undefined) => {
  
      let shieldCards = [...updatedCards];
  
      const cardIndex = personId ? shieldCards.findIndex((shieldCard) => {return shieldCard.card.id == personId}) : 0
  
      if ( !personId || cardIndex === -1 || !shieldCards[cardIndex]) return;
  
      shieldCards = shieldCards.map((shieldCard, index) => {
        const { card, active } = shieldCard
        return { card: card, active: (index==cardIndex)  }
      })
  
      updateCards(shieldCards)
    }  
    
      const cardsMap = updatedCards.map((updatedCard: { card: any; active: any }, index: number) => {
  
                const {card, active} = updatedCard
  
                if (card.id) {
                  return (
                    <CSSTransition
                      timeout={{ enter: 500, exit: 300 }}
                      className={`${active ? 'slideFade' : 'false'}`}
                      key={card.id}
                    >
                      <div>
                        {!active && <div className="cursor-pointer"
                            onClick={throttle(() => updateCardsById(card.id), 800)}
                          >
                            <ShieldCard 
                              {...card}
                            ></ShieldCard>
                        </div>}
                        { active &&
                            <ProfileCard
                              {...card}
                            ></ProfileCard>
                        }
                      </div>
                    </CSSTransition>
                  )
                }
  
              })
  
  
    return (
    <div className="py-8 px-4 pb-20 sm:pt-32 sm:pb-48`">
        <TransitionGroup   
            className="flex flex-wrap gap-x-8 gap-y-14 justify-center max-w-6xl w-5/6 m-auto"
            component="div"
        >
            {cardsMap}
        </TransitionGroup>

    </div>
    )
  }
```